# Sharing ASP.NET MVC site internally and externally

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, security

I want to build ASP.NET  MVC-3 web site that will have some reports.
mainly the web site consists of some reports that search data.
The reports will be available internally inside the company and externally.
internal staff has more reports, and even with the shared reports, will have more data to display and look for.

What are the best approach to do that.
internally the security will be based on windows-authentication.
Externally will be on active directory.

Comment: Sorry, you can't post specs to StackOverflow and expect us to write your code. What have you tried so far, and what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is about checking you are you say you are. Your question is about authorization. Which rights you have, what you can see or not.
I would use different roles for internal and external users. Based on your role you have more or less rights.